# Access currently running code from itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible for a python program to access its own code while running? I want to be able to detect random in-memory bit flips during runtime. I plan on recomputing a checksum of the currently running code (the entire file in memory, not just the currently running function) every few minutes to ensure it has not been corrupted.

Comment: Why do you think you need that? (and what if the code that performs checksum gets corrupted?)

Comment: Get yourself a computer with ECC memory if you need this level of checking, doing it in software is silly.